# Mixed Reality Capture Hololens Failure - Failed capturing photo (hr = 0x887A0005)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

Currently working on a feature in our Hololens application that allows the user to take Mixed Reality Capture photos on command.

My first stab at this involved verbatim copy and pasting the code snippets from this tutorial:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/locatable_camera_in_unity

Specifically, only the snippets in sections "Common Set Up for PhotoCapture" and "Capture a Photo to a File".

When testing in the Unity player, photo capture worked seamlessly.

However, when using the same feature when deployed to the Hololens, the following error would show up in the Debug log:

" Failed capturing photo (hr = 0x887A0005) "

In addition to this, OnCapturedPhotoToDisk callback function defined in my file and passed in as the OnCapturedPhotoToDiskCallback to the photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(...) function was not called at all.

I'm quite at a loss with how to proceed, besides looking to examples of using other API's to access Mixed Reality Capture. It seems to me there is a lot of seemingly contradictory information on the topic, or perhaps just a bunch of different API's to access the MRC resources available on the Hololens - but maybe I am just missing a very obvious detail!

Has anyone else seen such an error when trying to use this tutorial as a starting point?

P.S. Would like to mention that I am setting the Webcam and Microphone property to enabled in my Player Settings in Unity, as detailed in the tutorial.

(Posted concurrently via Hololens Forums:

http://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2309/mixed-reality-capture-hololens-failure-failed-capturing-photo-hr-0x887a0005/p1?new=1)

Comment: Are you using Vuforia? You need to disable Vuforia's capture before trying to take a photo.

Comment: I am actually not using Vuforia - but also I have since stopped working on the project